# how to classify weighted projective lines?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{WP}^1(1,a)$ be the weighted projective line where $(x_0:x_1)$ is identified with $(\lambda x_0:\lambda^a x_1)$. Some questions:

1) Is $\mathbb{WP}^1(1,a)$ smooth for all a?

2) When is $\mathbb{WP}^1(1,a)$  isomorphic to $\mathbb{WP}^1(1,b)$?

what about the projective plane? Is there an easy way to classify $\mathbb{WP}^2(1,a,b)$?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your terminology because theres an $n$ on the weighted projective line. In the weighted projective line, are you taking projective $n$ space with

$(x_{0}: \cdots : x_{n})$ identified with $(\lambda x_{0}, \lambda^{a} x_{1} : \cdots : \lambda x_{n})$?

Comment: sorry! originally i wanted to ask for a classification of projective space, and then I realized I don't even know how to do it for $n=1$, but forgot to change notation.

Comment: Do you know about toric varieties?

Comment: The question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3906280/weighted-projective-space-and-projective-space-are-isomorphic shows that the answer to 1) and 2) is YES.