# Weighted projective space and projective space are isomorphic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

From Vakil's book: Exercise 8.2.N

Show that the weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(m, n) = Proj(k[x, y])$ (where $x$ and $y$ have degrees $m$ and $n$ respectively) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Can anyone give an outline of the solution to this?

Edit:
For convenience I identify $k[x, y]$ with $k[u^m, v^n]$. I tried to see if there is any graded isomorphism between $k[u^m, v^n]$ and the graded ring  ${k[w, z]}^{(d)}$ for some $d$ that divides the gcd of $m$ and $n$. Then it would follow from the fact $\mathbb{P}^1 = Proj(k[w, z]) \cong Proj({k[w, z]}^{(d)})$. But I see that it isn't the case.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried and what do you know? For instance, have you engaged with the hint in the exercise at all? It's expected here that you do a bit more than just state a problem - without improvement your post will likely be closed.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for the advice, I am new to these forums. Actually, I tried some ideas of my own. I'll edit the post to add them too. The problem has two subproblems and the hint is given for the other subproblem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d$ be the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$. We write $m=m_{1}d,n=n_{1}d,l=m_{1}n_{1}d$.

Consider the morphism $\mathrm{Proj}(k[x,y]_{l})\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^{1}=\mathrm{Proj}(S,T)$ induced by the map of graded rings $S\mapsto x^{n_{1}}, T\mapsto y^{m_{1}}$, where $k[x,y]_{k}$ means the $l$th Veronese subring of $k[x,y]$ (Vakil.6.4.4). It's easily checked that this is an isomorphism. Since $\mathrm{Proj}(k[x,y]_{l})\simeq \mathrm{Proj}(k[x,y])$, we have $\mathbb{P}(m,n)\simeq \mathbb{P}^{1}$.